# Resizing Image From Graphics?

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm trying to resize my image after copying it from the screen, and can't figure out how to do it.  The tutorials I've been reading recommend using Graphics.DrawImage to resize the image, but when I run this code, it doesn't resize.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
g.CopyFromScreen(control.Parent.RectangleToScreen(control.Bounds).X, control.Parent.RectangleToScreen(control.Bounds).Y, 0, 0, new Size(control.Bounds.Width, control.Bounds.Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

g.DrawImage(b, 0,0,newWidth, newHeight);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where are you hoping for the resized image to be? You have a bitmap  that you don't actually use, and then an image that doesn't get defined in your code block.

Comment: Oops, I miswrote some code, and copied other code, and now it's inconsistent, thanks for pointing that out.  I will fix my post in a sec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. Graphics won't "replace" the image when you use DrawImage - it draws the input image on its source, which is the same as the the image you're trying to draw to it.

Probably a more concise way to do this but.....

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
   g.CopyFromScreen(control.Parent.RectangleToScreen(control.Bounds).X, 
      control.Parent.RectangleToScreen(control.Bounds).Y, 0, 0, 
      new Size(control.Bounds.Width, control.Bounds.Height),
      CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
Bitmap output = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(output)) {
  g.DrawImage(b, 0,0,newWidth, newHeight);
}
```

Comment: Need some `using` blocks.  `Graphics` objects need to be disposed.  There might not even be anything in `b` until `g` gets disposed.

Comment: Haha, and I was just extolling the virtues of "using" on another question having to do with datareaders. You are correct sir, updated.

Comment: With using blocks, do graphics objects still require disposing?

Comment: using automatically invokes Dispose(), that's it's purpose in life.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you can't just use a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) control?  That control takes care of stretching for you.